# Running one batch file silently and another normally, for USB auto backup

Tags: batch-file, usb, robocopy

this is my first time posting here so I'll do my best.
Basically I want to automatically backup my USB when it's plugged in, what I have set up at the moment is three files, backup.bat, silent backup.vbs, and backup watch.bat

Backup.bat

```
@echo off
Set _TS=        
Set _Source=C:\NMIT
Set _Dest=I:\Users\The Beast\SkyDrive\School\NMIT
Set _Log=I:\Users\The Beast\Documents\NMIT USB Backup Log.txt
robocopy "%_Source%" "%_Dest%" /E /ZB /B /V /PURGE /LOG:"I:\Users\The Beast\Documents\NMIT USB Backup Log.txt"
echo Backup complete, please remove USB
pause
```

Silent backup.vbs

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "I:\Users\The Beast\Desktop\testing bat\backup watch.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Backup watch.bat

```
@echo off

    IF EXIST "C:/NMIT" call "I:\Users\The Beast\Desktop\testing bat\backup.bat"
```

Everything works fine, runs, copies new files, and writes to the log file, also it runs silently thanks to the vbs scipt I found online, the only problem is I have no idea if it's done backing up or not, the script runs every 5 minutes by task scheduler. What I want to do is have the watch script run silently, but show a notification when the backup is done. I guess the easiest way to do that would be to edit backup.bat to include an echo and a pause, but if I do that now it's invisible, so how can I have the watch script run silent, but the backup script run normal? Thanks guys, I hope my post is descriptive enough.

Answer (score 0):

To create a notification, create a new file called `notify.bat` in the same directory:

```
@echo off
cls
set seconds=5
echo Backup complete, please remove USB
ping -n %seconds% 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
exit 0
```

Now change your `Backup.bat` script to:

```
@echo off
Set "_TS="        
Set _Source=C:\NMIT
Set _Dest=I:\Users\The Beast\SkyDrive\School\NMIT
Set _Log=I:\Users\The Beast\Documents\NMIT USB Backup Log.txt
robocopy "%_Source%" "%_Dest%" /E /ZB /B /V /PURGE /LOG:"I:\Users\The Beast\Documents\NMIT USB Backup Log.txt"
start notify.bat
```

The `Backup.bat` script will be hidden when called through the vbs file, but notify.bat will be visible since it's being called from the bat file instead.

Also, a small tip, to escape a quote inside of quotes, use double quotes. In `Silent backup.vbs` that would look like:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run """I:\Users\The Beast\Desktop\testing bat\backup watch.bat""", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```